# How do you display JSON Data in swiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, urlsession

I have problem with showing JSON Data in SwiftUI, I get the data from Genius API I currently search for song and can confirm that I get the data extracted correctly; example I can print out the title of the result:

[image]

This is how I fetch the data

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager, Never>()

    var fetchedSongsResults = [hits]() {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        fetchSongs()
    }

    func fetchSongs() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.genius.com/search?q=Sia") else { return }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.setValue("Bearer TOKEN", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            //print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
            let songs = try! JSONDecoder().decode(feed.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.fetchedSongsResults = songs.response.hits

            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

So when I get the data I save to the variable fetchedSongsResults and this seems correctly but for what ever reason when I try to print the count for example it says that i empty and also I can't loop through the fetchedSongsResults using a list or ForEach this is how, (which I believe s because I have not made the model identifiable) I tried to print the count of fetchedSongsResults,

This initialized outside the body (just so you know)

```
@State var networkManager = NetworkManager()
```

This is inside the body

```
Text("\(networkManager.fetchedSongsResults.count)")
```

If your are wondering how my structure looks like when I decode the JSON Data then here it is

```
struct feed: Codable {
   var meta: meta
   var response: response
}

struct meta: Codable {
   var status: Int
}

struct response: Codable {
   var hits: [hits]
}

struct hits: Codable {
   var index: String
   var type: String
   var result: song
}

struct song: Codable, Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var header_image_thumbnail_url: String
   var url: String
   var title: String
   var lyrics_state: String
   var primary_artist: artist

}

struct artist: Codable {
   var name: String
}
```

Comment: @State for NetworkManager looks wrong since this means the `networkManager` is somehow is tied to a user interface component which I suppose it isn't.

Comment: If the value in your Authorization header is private, you might want to remove it from your question.

Comment: Yes you are right and @ObservedObject solved the problem but I wanted to ask do you know why I cannot use in a list get the following error "Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager().

Comment: Yes it actually worked however I have another problem is that is I cannot use this with a list I get the following error "Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'"

Comment: your struct value is empty, try put some preset value to check whether this problem still exist

Comment: I tried you solution and it didn't work but thanks anyway